# refresh vb6 form in background without losing user entered data

Tags: forms, vb6, refresh

I'm working with some old VB6 code and have a scenario I'm trying to correct.  I have a form that allows you to enter a person ID (use renters this in a textbox at the top) and click "show" it lists the appointment in the textbox on the same form.  There is also a button that loads a new form that allows the user to edit the displayed data and save the change.

E.g. Change persons age from 65 to 64.  I make this change, and save it.  The save is successful and I unload the form to return to Form1.  However, I must click "show" again to refresh the displayed data in the textbox to ensure the change is visible.  I cannot figure out how to refresh this form, so the user doesn't have to click "show" to repopulate the textbox with the new value.  Can anyone assist?  I can't just create a new instance of Form1, because if I did that the person ID field would be blank.

Thanks!

Short version: How do I refresh a form to get latest data while still obtaining the relevant person ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Call Me.frmParent.Refresh
```

I used this to refresh the screen without losing data.
I had to dig through a lot of old code to figure it out.  This section had been written a long time ago, and worked well.

```
Public Sub Refresh()
Call cmdDetails_Click
If tvwScreeningSchedule.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
    tvwScreeningSchedule.SelectedItem = tvwScreeningSchedule.Nodes(1)
    Call tvwScreeningSchedule_Click
End If

End Sub
```

It's quite a specific function, and "cmdDetails_Click" contains alot of custom validation, but it's not too dis-similar to AngryHackers answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's not enough information here to answer your question. The general pattern you'd use in this situation is as follows:

1. SearchForm launches ViewForm.
2. ViewForm launches EditForm. When ViewForm constructs its instance of EditForm, it passes `Me` to EditForm (perhaps by setting EditForm.Parent).
3. When EditForm's Save button click event fires, it calls Parent.ReloadData (where Parent is the ViewForm that launched the EditForm).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach that should work.  In the editor have a public property that returns whether the form was cancelled or not. (.Cancelled).  You'll have an object that carries attributes of the person that you are trying to change the age of.  Then it's pretty simple.  Code in the main form:

```
dim oPerson as clsPerson
dim oFrm as frmAgeEditor

set oPerson = GetCurrentPerson()
set oFrm = new frmAgeEditor


with oFrm
    set .Person = oPerson
    .Show vbModal

    if not .Cancelled then
        ' Update Main form with the contents of oPerson

    end if

end with
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call in "Show" function right after updating.